# Add Listeners to Uploading Files with Service Context

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase documentation states that you can add listeners to Uploading File Tasks to Firebase Storage using an Activity scope to get them automatically unregistered if the Activity stops:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#handle_activity_lifecycle_changes

Is it possible to add listeners with Application or Service scope? What is the default scope used if you add listeners without defining an Scope?

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener...
```

versus

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no other types of scope for Tasks.  There is just Activity scope, and it tracks an Activity lifecycle.

If you want to use a Task in a service, you should be prepared to remove any listeners on a pending Task before the Service becomes destroyed, in whatever way that may happen for started and/or bound services.

Comment: Yes, my main issue is that even if my Service is still bound and/or running an uploading files, it seems my listeners are stopped or removed if I close my application. Does it mean that I'm using a wrong approach to make an uploading files feature that is available whether my app is active or not?
And also, then what is the default scope if you don't pass an Activity when adding a listener?

Comment: There's nothing you can do if Android chooses to kill your app, if that's now what you're asking.  If you want to handle that case, you'll need to remember for yourself which tasks were in progress and restart them when the app process is allowed to run again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also then what is the default scope if you don't pass an Activity when adding a listener?

Comment: There is no default scope. You remove the listeners when you're done.

Comment: say, here's a puzzle for you, men of Firebase!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454417  cheers